# Error:RenderBox was not laid out: NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: flutter, dart

i am having problem using `SingleChildScrollView` in this way, i dont no what is wrong, i keep getting this error.

If add the SingleChildScrollView the page will be blank(will not show all the widget)but if i remove the SingleChildScrollView, the page will show.

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#583c0 relayoutBoundary=up1
> NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1929
> pos 12: 'hasSize
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was Scaffold
> Scaffold:file:///Users/mac/Documents/Uneleap-Platform-master/lib/screens/Pages/forum/forum.dart:25:12

here is the code

```
SafeArea(
                minimum: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      WidgetForum(
                        details: 'The Get Is Not Geting together ?',
                        name: 'Nina Simon',
                        url: 'assets/dashboard_pic.png',
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      WidgetForum(
                        details:
                            '''Notes is designed for whatever’s on your mind.\nJot down your thoughts. Download Notes.\nThere is something wonderful in writing. \nThe Get Is Not Getting Together?''',
                        name: 'James Nugar',
                        url: 'assets/dashboard_pic.png',
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Topics',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 35,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.separated(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            separatorBuilder: (_, inedex) => SizedBox(
                                  width: 20,
                                ),
                            itemCount: topics.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/saved_2.png'),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                        child: Text(
                                          topics[index].schoolNmae!,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                      WidgetForum(
                        details:
                            '''Notes is designed for whatever’s on your mind.\nJot down your thoughts. Download Notes.\nThere is something wonderful in writing. \nThe Get Is Not Getting Together?''',
                        name: 'Sam Ajayi',
                        url: 'assets/dashboard_pic.png',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // bottomSheet:
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>((BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 250,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 50,
                          horizontal: 15.0,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  CustomIcons.answers_forum,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Post',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 120.0),
                              child: Divider(
                                thickness: 2,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  CustomIcons.create_forum,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Create Forum',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 70,
                                  width: 70,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
        
        class WidgetForum extends StatefulWidget {
          final String? name;
          final String? details;
          final String? url;
        
          WidgetForum(
              {Key? key, required this.name, required this.details, required this.url})
              : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          _WidgetForumState createState() => _WidgetForumState();
        }
        
        class _WidgetForumState extends State<WidgetForum> {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(widget.url!),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          widget.name!,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    PopupMenuButton(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      offset: Offset(0, 40),
                      itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
                        new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Fellow',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Block',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Report',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/library_pre.svg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 18),
                Text(
                  widget.details!,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 18),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          CustomIcons.icons8_up_2_11,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        Text('36'),
                        Icon(
                          CustomIcons.icons8_down,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          CustomIcons.answers_forum,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text('3')
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text('Sep 2, 2020')
                  ],
                ),
                Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                )
              ],
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 44):

You cannot use `Expanded` in `Column` if it has a parent `SingleChildScrollView` because When you use column it tries to be in screen height and when use expanded inside, The column will allocate remaining space to the child of the expanded widget, Now if you use `SingleChildScrollView` It will try to expand(by direction, vertically in your case) as long as possible but as you're using the Expanded which tries to take remaining space, So it goes infinite thus throws that error,

So Either remove `SingleChildScrollView` and use Column and expanded or remove the `Expanded` and Use `SingleChildScrollView` also make sure `ShrinkWrap` in `ListView` to true.

```
Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: const Text('Random widget'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 20,
            separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('Item at $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Or to Scroll all the widgets You can do using `SingleChildScrollView`

> Remove the `Expanded` widget here.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            'Hello, World!',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: const Text('Random widget'),
          ),
          ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 20,
              separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item at $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: still having the same error, i think is the way i layout all the widget

Answer (score 12):

Wrap it in a `Container` and add a height to it.
Fixed it for me.

Comment: Or better yet, a SizedBox with a height to it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by enclosing the `Column` widget in a `Container` widget that has a set `width` and `height`

Answer (score 1):

This code were raising the similar error

```
 Column(children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: CarouselSlider(
                            items: imageSliders,
                            carouselController: _controller,
                            options: CarouselOptions(
                                autoPlay: true,
                                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                aspectRatio: 2.0,
                                onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _current = index;
                                  });
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).product.productImages.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => _controller.animateToPage(entry.key),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 12.0,
                                height: 12.0,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: (Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                                            ? Colors.white
                                            : Colors.black)
                                        .withOpacity(_current == entry.key ? 0.9 : 0.4)),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ]),
```

To solved this, I remove the Expand Widget from it.
**Updated Code**

```
Column(children: [

                CarouselSlider(
                    items: imageSliders,
                    carouselController: _controller,
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        autoPlay: true,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        aspectRatio: 2.0,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                          setState(() {
                            _current = index;
                          });
                        }),
                  ),
               
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).product.productImages.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => _controller.animateToPage(entry.key),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 12.0,
                        height: 12.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: (Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.black)
                                .withOpacity(_current == entry.key ? 0.9 : 0.4)),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** use `Expanded` widget inside the `SingleChildScrollView`, just remove `Expanded` widget it is starts working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 scrolling widgets which is causing this issue. Column and Expanded can't be used while using SingleChildScrollView.

I encountered the same issue before, to fix it, remove the Expanded widget and  set `shrinkWrap: true,` in the `listview.seperated()`widget

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Expanded in Column if it has a parent SingleChildScrollView because When you use column it tries to be in screen height and when use expanded inside, The column will allocate remaining space to the child of the expanded widget, Now if you use SingleChildScrollView It will try to expand(by direction, vertically in your case) as long as possible but as you're using the Expanded which tries to take remaining space, So it goes infinite thus throws that error,

So Either remove SingleChildScrollView and use Column and expanded or remove the Expanded and Use SingleChildScrollView also make sure ShrinkWrap in ListView to true.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same problem. but in my case I was trying to provide row of widgets
for trailing property of the listTile class .and I solve it by wrapping the row with container and set its width.

Answer (score 0):

In one case, I got the same error.

When I scrolled to top of the log message, I found out the issue in below widget.I have wrapped the `Row` with `IntrinsicHeight` widget.

```
IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: []));
```

On removing `IntrinsicHeight` widget, it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Column** inside **SingleChildScrollView** throws this error since **Column** has an infinite height. The same happens with **ListView** if you add **Column** as one of its direct children.

This is how I nest my scrollable content instead:

```
SafeArea(
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      Text('Hello World!'),
      SizedBox(height: 100,
      Text('Put your long text here to test'),
    ]
  )
);
```

And it worked for me!

You're welcome. :)